# Macro used to convert .xls to .csv - Problem with where the converted file saved

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export, export-to-csv

The following micro is being use to convert an excel spreadsheet to a .csv file. My issue is that the converted .csv file (named final.csv) was saved in the folder that the original source file came from. Now, it is being saved in a whole other directory. I am not experienced in macros to find out why it is being saved in the wrong place.

```
WB.Close
MsgBox ("Done")
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub

Sub ExportSheetsToCSV()
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Filename = "Final.csv"
    
    'Copy the contents of required sheet ready to paste into the new CSV
    lr = Sheets("Upload Data").Columns("A").Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
    Set rng = Sheets("Upload Data").Range("A1:FB" & lr)
    rng.Copy
    
    'Open a new XLS workbook, save it as the file name
    Set WB = Workbooks.Add
    With WB
        .Title = "Upload Data"
        .Subject = "test"
        .ActiveSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs Filename, xlCSV
        .Close
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub
```

Comment: `Filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Final.csv"`?

Comment: Note that by using `xlCSV` you lose some control of the CSV appearance. Separator, quoting, possibly convering of strings with multiple numbers.  Excel tries to be smart for you, but it's not always desired, depending on purpose of CSV file.

Comment: @BigBen - I'm sorry, is that the resolution you are giving me? If so where do I insert that into the macro? I literally have no idea how to fix a broken macro.

Comment: Replace `Filename = "Final.csv"` with the line provided?